# How to make City optional?

Tags: magento2, checkout, html

I wanna make City optinal. I was made in JS a Dropdown so i can select the city. I put "city" textbox in display:none in CSS and next, copy onchange the dropbox text into this city textbox so the process don't broken.

But i see if i copy the text, the Magento mark me as "required" fiel.

The process is:

User select "Bogotá"
Script copy "Bogota" from de dropbox to the "City" textbox
User click "place order"
Magento 2 warning Textbox are empty (wen no, i check it)

If i remove a letter from the textbox (Bogotá to Bogot) and next put it again, the process continue without problem.

For this, i wanna make City optional cause i validate the textbox aren't empty.

Thanks.

Magento 2.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was found the solution myself.

Run this on your database:

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `is_required` = 0 WHERE `attribute_code` = 'city';
```

And it will be done!